# Jquery read uploaded file line by line

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to read a textfile which got uploaded line by line using jquery How would I be able to do this? My current code looks like the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Split input</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="file" id="file" />
    <input type='button' id='load-file' value='Load'>
    <div id="file-content"></div>
</body>

<script>        
    ( function ( $ ) {
        $( '#load-file' ).click( function () {

            if ( ! window.FileReader ) {
                return alert( 'FileReader API is not supported by your browser.' );
            }

            var $i = $( '#file' ), input = $i[0];

            if ( input.files && input.files[0] ) {
                file = input.files[0];
                fr = new FileReader();
                fr.onload = function () {
                    $( '#file-content' ).append( $( '<div/>' ).html( fr.result ) )
                };
                fr.readAsText( file );
            } else {
                alert( "File not selected or browser incompatible." )
            }
        } );
    } )( jQuery ); 
</script>
</html>
```

So I want to read each line inside the txt file after each other.

Comment: If the file is uploaded then you need to read it on the server. Presumably from your code sample you want to use a `FileReader` object to read the file on the client. If so, split the `fr.result` string by new line and the loop through the resulting array.

Comment: Do you want to read the file on your client side, right?